# Move Matrix colums based on a criteria

Tags: c, function

I'm trying in C to write a function that takes as an input an NxM matrix, and if it finds empty columns, to move the not empty columns to the left or to the right side of the matrix based on user's choice.The empty columns can be 1,2 or more.

As an example. Assuming the following matrix:

The matrix elements are:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
------------------
1| 1 6 0 0 0 1 0 8
2| 1 3 0 3 0 1 0 0
3| 3 0 0 0 0 8 0 0
4| 0 0 0 2 6 0 0 4
```

As you can see only the columns 3 and 7 are completely empty (all 0s). I want a function that if the user selects l (for left), it will move the not empty columns as they are to the left. So it will return:

The matrix elements are:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
------------------
1| 1 6 0 0 1 8 0 0
2| 1 3 3 0 1 0 0 0
3| 3 0 0 0 8 0 0 0
4| 0 0 2 6 0 4 0 0
```

If the user selects r (for right), it will move the not empty columns as they are to the right.So the function will return:

The matrix elements are:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
------------------
1| 0 0 1 6 0 0 1 8 
2| 0 0 1 3 3 0 1 0 
3| 0 0 3 0 0 0 8 0 
4| 0 0 0 0 2 6 0 4
```

This is my first aproach:

```
   void PushL(int (*arr), int rows, int cols){ //function to move columns to left 
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for(int j = 0;j < cols; j++){
                if(arr[i*cols+j] == 0)
                    for(int k = j + 1; k < cols; k++){
                        if(arr[i*cols+k] != 0){
                            arr[i*cols+j] = arr[i*cols+k];
                            arr[i*cols+k] = 0;
                            break;
                         }

                     }

           }
```

}

Comment: Could you improve the question. Currently it is unclear what is asked.

Comment: The is (at least) missing a description of the problem(s) with the current code. You should edit the question and add that. That said it seems to me that the code never checks if a column is completely empty...

Comment: You missed the `{ }` around the statements after the innermost `if`, so only the first statement is in the `if`, the others are only wrong intented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the problem concerning the missing {} your program does not work because you only consider cells valuing 0 or not independently of the other cells in the same column.

You need to know if *all* the column contains only 0 or not before to decide to move it or not

For that :

```
int onlyZero(int (*arr), int col, int rows, int cols)
{
  const int sup = cols*rows;

  for (int i = 0; i != sup; i += cols) {
    if (arr[i + col] != 0)
      return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

return 1 if the column *col* contains only 0, else 0

To copy a column in an other :

```
void copyColumn(int (*arr), int fromCol, int toCol, int rows, int cols)
{
  int sup = cols*rows;

  for (int i = 0; i != sup; i += cols)
    arr[i + toCol] = arr[i + fromCol];
}
```

and to reset a column :

```
void resetColumn(int (*arr), int col, int rows, int cols)
{
  int sup = cols*rows;

  for (int i = 0; i != sup; i += cols)
    arr[i + col] = 0;
}
```

Using these functions, even this is not the faster way :

```
void PushL(int (*arr), int rows, int cols)
{
  int receiver = 0;

  for (int col = 0; col != cols; ++col) {
    if (!onlyZero(arr, col, rows, cols)) {
      if (receiver != col)
        copyColumn(arr, col, receiver, rows, cols);
      receiver += 1;
    }
  }

  while (receiver != cols)
    resetColumn(arr, receiver++, rows, cols);
}
```

Adding

```
void pr(int (*arr), int rows, int cols)
{
  for (int row = 0; row != rows; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col != cols; ++col) {
      printf("%d ", arr[row*cols + col]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }
  putchar('\n');
}

int main()
{
  int a[] = { 
    1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 8,
    1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 2, 6, 0, 0, 4
  };

  pr(a, 4, 8);
  PushL(a, 4, 8);
  pr(a, 4, 8);
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall m.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1 6 0 0 0 1 0 8 
1 3 0 3 0 1 0 0 
3 0 0 0 0 8 0 0 
0 0 0 2 6 0 0 4 

1 6 0 0 1 8 0 0 
1 3 3 0 1 0 0 0 
3 0 0 0 8 0 0 0 
0 0 2 6 0 4 0 0
```

<s>I let you doing PushR which is very closed to PushL</s>

*PushR* is the symmetrical of *PushL* :

```
void PushR(int (*arr), int rows, int cols)
{
  int receiver = cols - 1;

  for (int col = cols-1; col != -1; --col) {
    if (!onlyZero(arr, col, rows, cols)) {
      if (receiver != col)
        copyColumn(arr, col, receiver, rows, cols); 
      receiver -= 1;
    }
  } 

  while (receiver != -1) 
    resetColumn(arr, receiver--, rows, cols);
}
```

Comment: TY Bruno!!! Is there a way to "join" all these to one function? For the pushR I changed in the PushR to go from the last column to the first like that.Where is the error? :   void PushR(int (*arr), int rows, int cols)
{
  int receiver = 0;

  for (int col=cols-1; col>0; --col) {
    if (!onlyZero(arr, col, rows, cols)) {
      if (receiver != col)
        copyColumn(arr, col, receiver, rows, cols);
      receiver += 1;
    }
  }

  while (receiver != cols)
    resetColumn(arr, receiver++, rows, cols);
}

Comment: @Mike as you can see the working functions are independent and there are called only one time on PushL, so yes you can put their body directly in PushL, but doing that you make the code less clear, and you will have to redo the same in PushR, so for me to do that is a bad idea. The more a code is clear/easy to read, the better it is.

Comment: @Mike you have 2 errors in your PushR, one concerning receiver and the other concerning the limit of the 2 fors. PushR must be symmetrical with PushL

Comment: as long as these functions are independent I "have" to re-use them for PushR. So the only that I can change to PushR is to go from max cols to 0.

Comment: @Mike not all if you do not find :-) I edited my answer to add PushR

Comment: bruno I tried all the others but I never changed this line: int receiver = cols - 1;    :) I prefer the for like that though: for (int col = cols-1; col >= 0; --col)   ! Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Bruno I want to printf a sentence like " There are no empty columns" if there aren't . When I put it in the onlyZero function like that it prints it several times. int onlyZero(int (*arr), int col, int rows, int cols)
{
  const int sup = cols*rows;

  for (int i = 0; i != sup; i += cols) {
    if (arr[i + col] != 0){
      printf("\nNone");
   return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}
}

Comment: @Mike my function _onlyZero just look at **one** column (_col_), not all. If you want to know if there are no 'empty' column you have to iterate on the columns or for performances just loop on the values without considering rows and columns just just an array of rows*columns _int_

Comment: I also put a counter++ before the return 1, to count how many "free columns" it found. If the function returns1, it found a free column,right; And then I said (if counter == 0) meaning it hasn't changed because it was firstly set to 0,  printf("\nNone");

Comment: @Mike I do not understand,  _counter_ is a global var ?

Comment: I set it outside of the functions so yes it is a global

Comment: @Mike **do not do that, the use of a global var like that is ugly**, and you do not need that at all, just modify PushX to have `if (!onlyZero(arr, col, rows, cols)) {...} else ++zeroCols;` with `int zeroCols = 0;` before the loop

Comment: @Mike you can also know the number of empty cols without the _zeroCols_ in my previous remark, in PushL it is `cols - receiver` before the _while_, and in PushR it is `receiver+1` before the _while_

Comment: Bruno Thank you! Finaly case closed!! :)

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the only problem, but both code segments shown in your original post are missing `{}` symbols, essential to the assumed intent.  (see `/// here`)

```
void PushR(int (*arr), int rows, int cols){
    for(int i = rows; i > 0; i--)
        for(int j = cols;j > 0; j--){
                if(arr[i*cols+j] == 0)
                    for(int k = j + 1; k < cols; k++){
                        if(arr[i*cols+k] != 0)
                        { /// here
                            arr[i*cols+j] = arr[i*cols+k];
                            arr[i*cols+k] = 0;/// without {} these lines will be executed
                            break;            /// regardless of if evaluation
                        } /// and here
                    }
        }
}
```

(Indentations in C are for readability only, and do not control execution flow.)

And to make code more readable for those that will maintain it in the future, it is really better to remove all ambiguity about intent:  (Include curly braces where intent is not otherwise explicitly known.)

```
void PushR(int (*arr), int rows, int cols){
    for(int i = rows; i > 0; i--) {/// added here
        for(int j = cols;j > 0; j--){
            if(arr[i*cols+j] == 0) { /// added here
               for(int k = j + 1; k < cols; k++){
                   if(arr[i*cols+k] != 0) { /// here
                       arr[i*cols+j] = arr[i*cols+k];
                       arr[i*cols+k] = 0;
                       break;
                   } /// and here
                }
            }
        }
     }    
 }
```

Comment: "_may not be the only problem_" hehe yes this is not the only problem, the OP missed to check a column only contains 0 or not before to decide to move it or not. Out of the subject, the emot is your airplane ?

Comment: @bruno - the icon is a goal :)  I recently sold a small Cessna and I am plane-less at the moment

Answer (score 0):

```
void test()
{
    int p[4][9] = {
        1 , 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 8,
        2 , 1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        3 , 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0,
        4 , 0, 0, 0, 2, 6, 0, 0, 4 };
    int pp[4][9] = {};


    int say = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    { 
        bool ok = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (p[j][i] != 0)
                ok = true;
        }

        if (ok)
        { 
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                pp[j][say] = p[j][i];
            say++;
        }

    }


    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", pp[j][i]);
        if (i == 8) printf("\n");
    }

}
```